# Finding a General Solution of an System of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Determine the general solution of the system

$$
\begin{split}
x'&=(3t-1)x-(1-t)y+te^{t^{2}}\\
y'&=-(t+2)x+(t-2)y-e^{t^{2}}
\end{split}
$$

Hint: The homogeneous system has a solution of the form $(x(t),y(t))= (\phi(t), -\phi(t))$

For this problem I attempted using the Method of Variation of Constants.

First I have the matrix $Y(t) = \begin{bmatrix} (3t-1)& -(1-t) \\ -(t+2) & (t-2) \end{bmatrix}$ and $b(t) = \begin{bmatrix} te^{t^{2}} \\ -e^{{t^2}} \end{bmatrix}$

Then $$Y^{-1}(t) = \frac{1}{4t^{2}-6t} \begin{bmatrix} t-2& 1-t \\ t+2 & 3t-1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: Did you calculate the FM or was it a given?

Comment: No, I was using the procedure of the Method of Variation of Constants for the system $y'(t)=A(t)y(t)+b(t)$. You are right that is not the Fundamental Matrix. Sorry I will edit that.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the solution of the homogeneous equation, make a transformation of variables to 
$$
v=\frac{x+y}2\\u=\frac{x-y}2
$$
or 
$$
x = v+u\\y=v-u
$$
The straightforward algebra on the two equations, substituting for $x$ and $y$, gives
$$
v' = \frac12 (t-1)e^{t^2}+(2t-3)v \\
u' = \frac12 (t+1)e^{t^2}+2tu (2t+1)v 
$$
The second of these is not immediately useful but the first is an ordinary  differential equation for $v(t)$ and its solution is
$$
v(t) = \left( C e^{-3t} + \frac{t}6-\frac29\right)e^{t^2}
$$
Now we can make use of the $u'$ equation, buy substituting this expression for $v(t)$.  Again we get an easily solved ordinatry differential equation; the solution is:
$$
u(t) = \left(+\frac{2t^3+2t^2+5t}{18} -\frac{6t+5}9 C e^{-3t} +K \right)e^{t^2} 
$$
Adding $v+u$ gives $x$; subtracting gives $y$.

Comment: Thanks. How does the hint for the problem apply to your solution?